# Does no/low-correlation variables matter in KNNimputer?

Tags: python

I have multiple variables (20) with NaNs and I want to fill them, I am using

> KNNImputer and a new data without NaNs to improve correlation, inserting variables to fill 1by1

to do it, but:

-I am not sure if is best select 5 variables very correlated or 15 including low correlated,or 20 including all.How many variables must handle KNNImputer to do it's best?

Can anyone response this questions? Thank you

Comment: Here's my understanding: If 2 or more of your features have high positive correlations, it means they are measuring the same thing, so it's a good idea to keep only 1 of these. In contrast if the features have low correlation, it means they are measuring something different, and it's generally a good idea to keep them. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Each use case is different and I don't think there's a fixed number of variables that guarantees a good outcome, trial and error with different combinations perhaps, and use the best combinations.